# How to drop a table inside a loop - WITHOUT dynamic or stored oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

Could you please help me resolve this?

I cannot use Execute immediate, nor have a stored proc to do it for me. Also global temp table is not an option.

I need to drop a table inside my LOOP statement.

How to do this?

Thank you

```
V_VAR:=1;
While V_VAR<>0;
BEGIN LOOP

<my working inner loop code here which generates data from MYTABLE to MYRESULT>

DROP TABLE MYTABLE; -- ERROR HERE Excpected .....
CREATE MYTABLE ();

INSERT INTO MYTABLE SELECT ... FROM MYRESULT

Select nvl(Count(*),0) into V_VAR from MYTABLE;
END LOOP;
```

*(I'm having a double loop: an inner and an outer. 
The inner one does the job, but due to it's nature it needs to be ran X times until all iterations of the issues is handled. 
So at the end of the inner code i need to re initiate the work data in the original table from the output table so i can run the next iteration.*

```
 Source -> run the inner loop -> Calculated data -> transform to the source format -> overwrite the source with the new iteration -> run the inner loop
```

etc.

*My issue is that e.g. in MSSQL i'd just drop/truncate the table in the outer loop, and insert into the new transformed data for the next version.
But when i try to do this in Oracle i get the error that it does not expect drop/truncate in the loop.
)*

Edit 2: 
The original issue is that i need to stack lead times. if you stack them, you'll need to stack them again, until you got no gaps in them. So i must run my same iterative by row code, multiple times until. So to do this i have a working (fast, tested) loop, which i loop until my count of gaps is 0. As my code works on a given table and structure, to be able to loop it N times, i need to feed the output back to the original table to be iterated again. There is a calc step on output which i can't just "update" to my orig table (lot of group bys).

Comment: you should probably post a minimal code example that exhibits this problem.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't. LOOP = PL/SQL. DROP TABLE = DDL. if you want to execute DDL in PL/SQL, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You can't execute DDL in PL/SQL. I think you might want to use a global temporary table: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/global_temp.php

Comment: Instead of dropping a re-creating the table, why don't you simply replace the contents?

Comment: global temp is also not an option :( Dan: what do you mean? I get the same expecting ... error when i try to use truncate.

Comment: Not possible. You can't run DDL statements in PL/SQL without dynamic SQL. You are already using PL/SQL, so why can't you use dynamic SQL? You don't need a stored procedure for that

Comment: Dropping and re-creating a table inside a loop seems a rather strange approach to begin with. This is not how relational databases work (and definitely not a good approach for Oracle) Maybe you should take a step back and explain the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve, rather then trying to apply a pattern that is simply not suitable for Oracle (or a relational database)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : DBA rules :( no exception. The original issue is that i need to stack lead times. if you stack them, you'll need to stack them again, until you got no gaps in them. So i must run my same iterative by row code, multiple times until. So to do this i have a working (fast, tested) loop, which i loop until my count of gaps is 0. As my code works on a given table and structure, to be able to loop it N times, i need to feed the output back to the original table to be iterated again. There is a calc step on output which i can't just "update" to my orig table (lot of group bys)

Comment: You are allowed to use PL/SQL, and you are allowed to create and drop tables on the fly but you are not allowed to do that using PL/SQL? That sounds like a stupid restriction. You should ask your DBA how he/she expects you to do DDL inside PL/SQL then (assuming that your approach makes sense to begin with - which I highly doubt)

Comment: Dropping and re-creating a table is an anti-pattern.  Try re-asking what you are trying to accomplish and not how to make an anti-pattern work.   This community will help you with performing work that is more appropriate.